# function not outputting as expected when utilizing array

Tags: c++, arrays

Good Afternoon Everyone,

I am having issues getting a function to output as expected for a payroll program that I am working on. I added an array so that I may differentiate between employees (employee 1, 2, 3, etc.). This is for a payroll program which the user is prompted to enter hours for each employee (7 total). These hours are then separately calculated to multiply the hours by pay rate to display the gross pay for each employee. Here is my code so far:

**Payroll.h**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Payroll
{
public:
    Payroll();
    void setHourlyPayRate(double), setHoursWorked(double), setTotalWeeklyPay(double);
    double getHourlyPayRate();
    double getHoursWorked();
    double getTotalWeeklyPay();
private:
    double hourlyPayRate, hoursWorked, totalWeeklyPay;
};

Payroll::Payroll()
{
    hourlyPayRate = 0.0;
    hoursWorked = 0.0;
    totalWeeklyPay = 0.0;
}

void Payroll::setHourlyPayRate(double hpr)
{
    hourlyPayRate = hpr;
}
double Payroll::getHourlyPayRate()
{
    return hourlyPayRate;
}
void Payroll::setHoursWorked(double hw)
{
    hoursWorked = hw;
}
double Payroll::getHoursWorked()
{
    return hoursWorked;
}
void Payroll::setTotalWeeklyPay(double twp)
{
    totalWeeklyPay = twp;
}
double Payroll::getTotalWeeklyPay()
{
    return totalWeeklyPay;
}
```

**Payroll.cpp**

```
/*Include Section*/
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include "Payroll.h"

/*Namespace Section*/
using namespace std;

void displayPayroll(Payroll * const, int);

/*Main section: this is the entry point of the program, which controls the flow of execution*/
int main()
{
    const int employee = 7; /*array of employees with maximum of 7*/
    int employeeNumber[employee] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 };
    Payroll payCycle[employee];

    /*Beginning of program. Outputs the following to the user, prompting them to enter the number of hours worked for each of the 7 employees*/
    cout << "*******************************************************************************" << endl
        << setw(48) << "Monthly Payroll" << endl
        << "*******************************************************************************" << endl;
    for (int index = 0; index < employee; ++index)
    {
        double hpr, hw, twp; /*initializes hourly rate, hours worked, and twp mutators, accepting decimal values*/
        hpr = 7.75; /*Sets hourly pay rate at $7.75*/
        char decision = 'Y';

        cout << "Enter the number of hours worked for employee " << (index + 1) << ": "; /*looks to array to determine employee number\count*/
        cin >> hw; /*user enters hours worked*/

        while (hw >= 61) /*prompts the following outputs to the user if hours worked is greater than maximum value of 60*/
        {
            cout << "ERROR: Hours must be between 0 and 60" << endl
                << "Are the hours you entered correct (Y or N)?  ";
            cin >> decision;

            if (decision == 'Y' || decision == 'y')
            {
                cout << endl << "Hours above 60 are considered overtime. Please contact management." << endl << endl;
                exit(0);
            }
            else if (decision == 'N' || decision == 'n')
            {
                cout << "Please re-enter the total number of hours worked:  ";
                cin >> hw;
            }
        }
        twp = hpr * hw; /*calculates employee's gross pay for the week by multiplying hourly pay rate by hours worked*/

        payCycle[index].setHourlyPayRate(hpr);
        payCycle[index].setHoursWorked(hw);
        payCycle[index].setTotalWeeklyPay(twp);
    }
    /*Outputs employee gross pay totals to user, utilizing the twp calculations above*/
    cout << endl
        << "*******************************************************************************" << endl
        << setw(52) << "Employee Gross Pay Totals" << endl
        << "*******************************************************************************" << endl;
    for (int index = 0; index < employee; ++index) 
    {
        displayPayroll(Payroll * const, int); /* calls to displayPayroll function in order to display gross pay for each of the 7 employees*/
    }

    system("PAUSE");
}
void displayPayroll(Payroll * const e, int index)
{
    /*const int employee = 7;
    int employeeNumber[employee] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 };
    Payroll payCycle[employee];

    for (int index = 0; index < employee; ++index)
        cout << "Employee " << (index + 1) << "'s gross pay for this period: $" << e->getTotalWeeklyPay() << endl;*/
    //cout << "Employee's gross pay for this period: $" << e->getTotalWeeklyPay() << endl;
    cout << "Employee " << (index + 1) << "'s gross pay for this period: $" << e->getTotalWeeklyPay() << endl;
}
```

**output**

```
*******************************************************************************
                                 Monthly Payroll
*******************************************************************************
Enter the number of hours worked for employee1: 1
Enter the number of hours worked for employee2: 2
Enter the number of hours worked for employee3: 3
Enter the number of hours worked for employee4: 4
Enter the number of hours worked for employee5: 5
Enter the number of hours worked for employee6: 6
Enter the number of hours worked for employee7: 7

*******************************************************************************
                           Employee Gross Pay Totals
*******************************************************************************
Employee 1's gross pay for this period: $7.75
Employee 2's gross pay for this period: $7.75
Employee 3's gross pay for this period: $7.75
Employee 4's gross pay for this period: $7.75
Employee 5's gross pay for this period: $7.75
Employee 6's gross pay for this period: $7.75
Employee 7's gross pay for this period: $7.75
Employee 1's gross pay for this period: $15.5
Employee 2's gross pay for this period: $15.5
Employee 3's gross pay for this period: $15.5
Employee 4's gross pay for this period: $15.5
Employee 5's gross pay for this period: $15.5
Employee 6's gross pay for this period: $15.5
Employee 7's gross pay for this period: $15.5
Employee 1's gross pay for this period: $23.25
Employee 2's gross pay for this period: $23.25
Employee 3's gross pay for this period: $23.25
Employee 4's gross pay for this period: $23.25
Employee 5's gross pay for this period: $23.25
Employee 6's gross pay for this period: $23.25
Employee 7's gross pay for this period: $23.25
Employee 1's gross pay for this period: $31
Employee 2's gross pay for this period: $31
Employee 3's gross pay for this period: $31
Employee 4's gross pay for this period: $31
Employee 5's gross pay for this period: $31
Employee 6's gross pay for this period: $31
Employee 7's gross pay for this period: $31
Employee 1's gross pay for this period: $38.75
Employee 2's gross pay for this period: $38.75
Employee 3's gross pay for this period: $38.75
Employee 4's gross pay for this period: $38.75
Employee 5's gross pay for this period: $38.75
Employee 6's gross pay for this period: $38.75
Employee 7's gross pay for this period: $38.75
Employee 1's gross pay for this period: $46.5
Employee 2's gross pay for this period: $46.5
Employee 3's gross pay for this period: $46.5
Employee 4's gross pay for this period: $46.5
Employee 5's gross pay for this period: $46.5
Employee 6's gross pay for this period: $46.5
Employee 7's gross pay for this period: $46.5
Employee 1's gross pay for this period: $54.25
Employee 2's gross pay for this period: $54.25
Employee 3's gross pay for this period: $54.25
Employee 4's gross pay for this period: $54.25
Employee 5's gross pay for this period: $54.25
Employee 6's gross pay for this period: $54.25
Employee 7's gross pay for this period: $54.25
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I've been looking at this for hours now and can't make heads or tails as to what is causing this. I'm pretty new to c++, so it's likely something simple that I'm missing or overlooking.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: You call displaypayroll() method for every emloyee and it prints it for every employee too. Revise this function to primt only certain employee's data

Comment: This problem is easily spotted if instead of looking at the code you walk through it in your head, on a piece of paper, or using the debugging software that almost certainly came with your development system . You will quickly see that for every employee you call `displaypayroll` which prints out every employee.

Comment: t.m.: thank you for the info. I'm a bit unsure how I would do so to get it to output one entry per employee.

Comment: (Undercover work for a trade union?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call your function `displayPayroll()` in your main, you do so in a for loop that iterates through 7 calls. Then, in your function `displayPayroll()` you have another for loop that iterates through 7 calls.

Remove one of the for loops.

Also, it would be a good idea for your main to return an integer upon completion.

Comment: Thank you for help! When I try to remove a for loop, it gives me an "identifier index is undefined" error. I'm also unsure of where the displayPayroll() would go if outside of the main. I apologize, as I am pretty new to this. I know it's probably something easy that I cannot see yet.

Comment: change your payroll function to be only one line long and that line is just your cout statement.

Comment: when I comment out everything else in the displayPayroll function and have only the "cout << "Employee " << (index + 1) << "'s gross pay for this period: $" << e->getTotalWeeklyPay() << endl;", that's when I get the undefined error.

Comment: here is what it looks like now:void displaypayroll(Payroll * const e)
{
 //const int employee = 7;
 //int employeeNumber[employee] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 };
 //Payroll payCycle[employee];
 //for (int index = 0; index < employee; ++index)
  cout << "Employee " << (index + 1) << "'s gross pay for this period: $" << e->getTotalWeeklyPay() << endl;
}

Comment: Try this.
displayparoll prototype: `void displaypayroll(Payroll * const, int);`
definition: `void displaypayroll(Payroll * const e, int index) { cout << "Employee " << (index + 1) << "'s gross pay for this period: $" << e->getTotalWeeklyPay() << endl; }`

Comment: I tried that, but get errors "type name is not allowed" and syntax error: 'const'  for the prototype you gave. I've modified my cpp code to show you

Comment: you also changed the syntax of the for loop<br/>

Comment: when you call the displaypayroll function in your for loop it should be `displayPayroll(&payCycle[index], index);`

Comment: that was it. Seriously Phabi0, I cannot thank you enough for all your help! I'm working very hard to get better at this, but a lot of it is still very confusing to me. I truly appreciate it!

Comment: no sweat, please mark the answer of your choice as accepted.

Comment: would you possibly be able to take a look at another error I'm having. It's an LNK2019 error and I'm not sure what is going on. I'd greatly appreciate any help you can give!: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41078795/lnk2019-errors-when-attempting-to-run-program